# Chef Client Output not Redirected Event with Redirect

Tags: ruby, batch-file, chef-infra

I have a bat file that calls chef-client (as well as other things). When I redirect the output of my batch file to a file, it doesn't print the output of chef-client, but I can't understand why.

For example, I have test.bat with only this line (I've simplified it to this to isolate the problem, but in reality has more)

```
call chef-client %*
```

This prints

```
Starting Chef Client, version 12.13.37
```

followed by rest of output

Doing this

```
test.bat > test.log 2>&1
```

prints nothing to test.log (it creates an empty file)

If I even take the contents of chef-client.bat and call it directly, I see the same results:

```
C:\opscode\chef\embedded\bin\ruby.exe C:\opscode\chef\bin\chef-client remoteapp::default > C:\test.log 2>&1
```

prints nothing to test.log

but removing the redirection prints

```
Starting Chef Client, version 12.13.37
```

as I would expect. How can I get redirection to file working here?

Answer (score 0):

Some programs detect that standard input or output has been redirected to a file (not a terminal) and do something else (or nothing)

You have stumbled on such a program.

Comment: Is there a way to override?

Comment: Maybe with a python wrapper. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186035/can-you-fool-isatty-and-log-stdout-and-stderr-separately/34360201#34360201  (as you see it's not very easy)