# How to make a script think it's running using a termnal?

Tags: python, windows, stdout, tty, sys

I am using a python script(x.py) that required to be run using terminal, but I have a large list that need to be iterate so I did a script that can call the x.py but I could not save the output due to sys.stdout.isatty(), how can I make python script think it runs using `atty` device?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by `think it runs using terminal` ? or you could check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858623/how-to-recognize-whether-a-script-is-running-on-a-tty)

Comment: @Onyambu I want to run it using python IDE not the terminal and I do not have control over the original script

Answer (score 0):

You can monkey patch `isatty` to `lambda x: True`

another hack is at

[Can you fool isatty AND log stdout and stderr separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186035/can-you-fool-isatty-and-log-stdout-and-stderr-separately)

Answer (score 0):

I've used 'unbuffer' which is part of the 'expect' package.  Search for unbuffer in this page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_output_in_console